# Is a multisite install what I need?

Tags: multisite, membership, globals

I have a client who owns a chain of clubs - all of them unique and requiring different sites, however, there will be one GLOBAL login for members.

The members area will include things like club deals, booking in forms, VIP info etc but needs to be the same for all sites. Can someone tell me if a multisite with a membership plugin is what I need to accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: You want to log in to all sites with one username/password?

Comment: Yes, so members of one site are members of all the others

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a multisite is what you need.

The membership part is arguably a separate question, and there are many ways of doing it. I would suggest a dedicated members site users register to, but there are lots of other ways of doing it, and there is no definitive answer.

[See here for what to do before you create a network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network)

[This is how you'd create a network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Follow up questions for you to ask or research that would be useful:

- How do I programmatically add a user on a site to all other sites

Booking and so on are highly bespoke systems, and very specific and localised, I doubt you'd be able to ask a truly useful question here without it devolving into plugin recommendation or too localised close votes.

If you require payment for membership, that is yet another question, and one that depends entirely on the payment gateways and membership plugins you use. Asking for recommendations for membership plugins here would also be offtopic and result in a closed question as there is no definitive right or wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need a multisite network then make sure your plugin is **compatible** with Multsite network and have the options you looking for. Then you are good to go.

If you are not going to use any plugin, then simply just add all users of your Multsite to all of your sites and give them the same permission.

To enable Multisite, simply open your wp-config.php file located in your WordPress root folder. Then add the following line anywhere in the file:
         define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

Comment: Creating a Multisite install is a little more complicated than adding the `WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE` constant -- but not much.  Read [Before You Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network) and [Create A Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) for more details.

Comment: Yeah sorry consedring that the install are allready done...@Pat J

Answer (score 0):

User profiles are shared across your multisite network. If your membership system creates new WordPress users (it should), then you should be able to have them join the primary site. If you want them on the subsites, what you will need to check is whether your membership system shares the membership info across other sites, and figure out how to add them to those particular site.

What membership systems are you looking at?